# Ansible merges group_vars when deploying to same host in different groups

Tags: ansible

Here's an example of the problem:

**inventory file:**

```
[group1] www.example1.com

[group2] www.example1.com
```

**group_vars files:**

```
group_vars/group1:
    a_var: aaa

group_vars/group2:
    a_var: bbb
```

If we run this playbook:

```
- name: ...
  hosts: group1
  roles:
    - ...
```

The variables from group_vars/group1 and group_vars/group2 overwrite each other if we're deploying to the same server.

**Expected result:**
a_var=aaa

**Actual result:** 
a_vars=bbb

It seems like the vars get parsed and attached to the host rather than the staying with the group (so group_vars get merged even if you are not using that group and last group merged wins !!!!). is that a normal behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is that a normal behavior ?

Yes, if host is in multiple groups, variables from only one group (the latter) will be honored.

From [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html):

> It is ok to put systems in more than one group, for instance a server could be both a webserver and a dbserver. If you do, note that variables will come from all of the groups they are a member of, and variable precedence is detailed in a later chapter.

Comment: _Unfortunately_, this overwriting is considered normal. At least for hashes, it would've been more sensible to actually _merge_ them together, instead of following "the last one wins" principle.

Comment: Indeed, this is an extremely annoying "feature" of Ansible.  It makes true hierarchical management of settings very difficult.  I don't think Ansible even exposes a `groupvars` like setting as it does `hostvars` during a run.

Answer (score 11):

As a workaround, you can choose a different name for each group and set the var ansible_host for each with true hostname/IP. Example:

```
[group1]
example1-group1 ansible_host=192.168.0.10

[group2]
example1-group2 ansible_host=192.168.0.10
```

In this case, Ansible considers that you have two different hosts, with dedicated hostvars and groupvars but reaches them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is a feature it becomes really annoying when you are using a local ansible connection to manage remote resources like databases.

I managed to get around this by using a unique name in the hosts in the hosts file.

The following playbook (`print.yml`) will print `db1` and changing the hosts to `group2` will print `db2`

```
---
- name: Manage DB
  hosts: group1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ database.name }}"
```

Inventory folder:

```
dev
├── group_vars
│   ├── group1
│   │   └── all.yml
│   └── group2
│       └── all.yml
└── hosts
    └── all.yml
```

group_vars/group1/all.yml:

```
database:
  name: db1
```

group_vars/group2/all.yml:

```
database:
  name: db2
```

and contents of hosts/all.yml:
(NOTE: the `dbnode1` vs `dbnode2` below)

```
all:
  children:
    group1: 
      hosts:
        dbnode1:
          ansible_connection: local
    group2: 
      hosts:
        dbnode2:
          ansible_connection: local
```

```
ansible -i dev print.yml
```